# slickgrid can't scroll to the bottom

Tags: slickgrid

i don't know what happen. i just load my data with json and applying paging with dataView. the data is displayed well but i can't scrolling to the bottom. so when i click "25" to show 25 rows, the table only display 24 rows. same if i click "50", "100" or all rows.
i check with firebug, the JSON response is complete. 
i tried to inspect element in the browser, compare mine with file "examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html". and i got this:
**.slick-viewport** has **height: 452px;**
and on the example file
**.slick-viewport** has **height: 473px;**

and if i change the height in firefox with inspect element feature. i can see the bottom of data.
how do i solve this?
here is my code http://pastebin.com/vqYEW1Zg

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you have twice `multiColumnSort: true` in your `var options` definition, without a comma at the end of the first one.

Comment: it's commented and it's one line #71

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to loop through your data with a dataView object, by just binding the getJSON result data with `dataView.setItems(data)` is all you need. The loop is required only when not using a dataview. So remove that loop inside your getJSON and have this code at the end of your getJSON function:

```
$.getJSON(ajaxFileURL,ajaxUpdateURL,function(data){
    // all your previous code...        

    // initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(data);
    dataView.endUpdate();
}); // end of getJSON
```

As for the rest, you should also look at your previous question, I also replied you and modified the code sample there...